# Getting the Parent DOM Element of an Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML Code that I inherited. I am not sure if having a button element inside a table element is best practise but that's what I'm given.

I need to be able to get to the `<table>` (parent) element from the `<button>` (child) element. I tried using .parent() or .closest() but it's not working for the HTML that I give it.

Any suggestions to get the JS to work ? here is the JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nvjamtLo/2/

```
function f1(event)
{
$.when(
$(this).parent('table#fsg').css("background-color", "red"),
console.log('gff'))
}
```

Comment: `$("#dfg").parent().css("background-color", "red")` - there's no need to put anything inside braces in the `parent()` function.

Comment: That duplicate suggestion IN THIS CASE will not work to answer the question due to the structure of the table.

Comment: That is correct, I know the typical usage of .parent() is simple, but my XML structure wasn't allowing it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things happen with your example in the fiddle.

- First off the button THERE will render OUTSIDE the table in many browsers - that is invalid HTML.
- second your code is just odd - `$.when`? what is that for?
- third your code is never executing the function - like you normally would on a click of the button for example.
- you are often better adding a class than CSS directly, modification of the CSS may not always do what you wish.
- selecting a table containing a button by the ID is better than the tag and the id i.e. `#mytableid` is better than `table#mytableid` - especially given the right to left selector nature of the sizzle engine - that says (find an element by id (fast) THEN find a table with that id (not as fast) - since an ID is unique in a document just use that.
- to traverse from a button UP to a parent element use `.parents()` with the selector i.e. `.parents("#mytableid")`  OR if you do not know the id just `.parents('table')`

  - NOTE I used `.parents()` here NOT the singular `.parent()` as that would get the parent element but that table is NOT the parent of the `button`, it is the ancestor of the button

SO, given that here is a partial update of html and the code to do something with it.

```
function f1(event) {
    $(this).parents('#fsg').addClass('myred');
    console.log('gff');
}
$('#dfg').on('click',f1);
```

HTML with button moved:

```
<table id="fsg">
  <tr>
    <th>Company
      <button id="dfg">
        text
      </button>
    </th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Updated fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/vyukyqsu/1/

Comment: $.when is indeed weird, I am using this to load a loader GIF in an div somewhere, but for some reason I removed it in JSFiddle. Provides an easy way to have callback functions execute (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Also I ended up modifying my HTML structure so I no longer have to use the .parent API. But I appreciate the write up

Answer (score 2):

Please mind that: although you put the button "inside" the table - **it is not valid**.

if you inspect the element (on chrome: right click the button -> choose inspect element from the menu), you will clearly see that the button is placed **outside** the table element

that is also why changing the parent selector from:

```
$("button#dfg").parent('table#fsg').css("background-color", "red")
```

to:

```
$("button#dfg").parent().css("background-color", "red")
```

will paint the entire body with a red background

Conslusion: when you use a table - please place the button as a valid table element (inside a td element)

Answer (score 2):

A table cannot contain a button immediately after the table definition. For details see [HTML  element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Instead, you can insert a button in a cell. In this case you can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). But, because your table has an id you may simply refer to it.

The snippet:

```js
$("#fsg").css("background-color", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="fsg">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="dfg">text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to change the background color of the table you don't need the parent property you can access the element via its ID

```
$(function(){
    $("#dfg").click(function(){
      $("#fsg").css("background-color","red");
   });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4v69cda/